# Can't get full result of a html-query

Tags: html, api, request, limit

I'm trying to scrape some date from this Webpage: https://ag.recapp.ch/viewer/api/search/?language_id=2&page.number=3&deputy_id=157&limit=50

This works quite well, but here's my problem: If I raise the limit over 50, the website responses less results. Any number below 50 seems to work. And yes, there are more then 50 results. I also tryed other parameters like "page=2", to get the rest of the query, but without success.

Anyone an Idea, how I can access the full result?

Comment: Please explain "without success", copy debug information from the console, show relevant parts of your code, copy fragments to help identify the problem.

Comment: The stuff you are trying to read is in JSON format, no need to scrape anything, you can just read and decode the data. It's not ment to be downloaded all data at once. You should follow the URL in the `nextCursor` field to get all data. Looking at the variables, you can see that `page` doesn't really exist, `limit` has boundaries and `offset` is used.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is not called scraping, my fault. Thanks for that hint, I could solve the problem with using offset! Thanks a lot!!